# How to make small native browser buttons with non round corners?

Tags: html, css, button

I just want to make rectangular buttons. Browsers are acting weird. This HTML:

```
<button style="height:19px; width: 37px; float: left;">19</button>
<button style="height:20px; width: 37px; float: left;">20</button>
<button style="height:21px; width: 37px; float: left;">21</button>
<button style="height:22px; width: 37px; float: left;">22</button>
<button style="height:26px; width: 37px; float: left;">26</button>
<button style="height:27px; width: 37px; float: left;">27</button>
```

...produces these varying results in different browsers:

[image: xxx]

Weird, right?

As for my actual question, I like the rectangular buttons. Any way I can get that look even for the smaller sizes?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this should reset everything, so that they look the same cross-browser.

```
button {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sUan8/

Then just add your own styles that you want..

for example

```
button {
   border: 1px solid grey;
   border-bottom: none;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px -2px grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution

CODE

```
button { border-radius:0; border:1px solid #000}
```

Crossbrowser Solutiuon

```
button { 
     border : 0px;
    -moz-border-radius:7px;
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;
     border-radius:7px;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/6Ywvk/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the following CSS property.

```
border-radius: 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

add `border-radius:0px;` and `border:1px solid black;`